# Extract exact value from stdout_lines from Ansible debug

Tags: ansible

I got my playbook from which I get value what I need through debug method, However I am not able to get exact value of child of my debug var

Below is my playbook

```
- hosts: db
  tasks:
  - name: Checking if For Page Life Expectancy.
    win_command: sqlcmd -q "SELECT [object_name],[counter_name],[cntr_value] FROM sys.dm_os_performance_counters WHERE [object_name] LIKE '%Manager%'AND [counter_name] = 'Page life expectancy'"
    register: win_command_result


  - debug:
      var: win_command_result.stdout_lines.object_name
```

And We get output like this

```
TASK [debug]
```

---

```
ok: [db1.local] => {
    "win_command_result": {
        "changed": true, 
        "cmd": "sqlcmd -q \"SELECT [object_name],[counter_name], 
               [cntr_value] FROM sys.dm_os_performance_counters WHERE [object_name] 
                LIKE '%Manager%'AND [counter_name] = 'Page life expectancy'\"", 
        "delta": "0:00:01.099974", 
        "end": "2018-09-11 05:08:36.022907", 
        "failed": false, 
        "rc": 0, 
        "start": "2018-09-11 05:08:34.922933", 
        "stderr": "", 
        "stderr_lines": [], 
        "stdout": "object_name                                                                                                                      
                   counter_name                                                                                                                     
                   cntr_value          \r\n--------------------------- 
  ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- --------------------\r\nSQLServer:Buffer Manager                                                                                                         
                            Page life expectancy                                                                                                                           
                            238579\r\n\r\n(1 rows affected)\r\n", 
        "stdout_lines": [
            "object_name                                                                                                                      
             counter_name                                                                                                                     
             cntr_value          ", 
            "--------------------------------------------------------- 
            ----------------------------------------------------------------------- -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- --------------------", 
            "SQLServer:Buffer Manager                                                                                                         
             Page life expectancy                                                                                                                           
             238579", 
            "", 
            "(1 rows affected)"
        ] 
    }
}
```

We only need value of ***cntr_value*** which is ***238579***

If i set as I though that cntr_value is child of stdout_lines

```
  - debug:
      var: win_command_result.stdout_lines.cntr_value
```

It says

```
ok: [db1.local] => {
    "win_command_result.stdout_lines.cntr_value": "VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!"
}
```

How do I extract exact value of ***cntr_value***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your output final variable is:

```
myvar.win_command_result.stdout
```

So if you want to extract the number, do a regex:

```
- name: Debug
  debug:
    msg: "{{ myvar.win_command_result.stdout | regex_search('\\d{6}')}}"
```

Another option:

```
- name: Fact
  set_fact:
    mylist: "{{ myvar.win_command_result.stdout_lines | list }}"

- name: Debug
  debug:
    msg: "{{ item | regex_search('\\d+') }}"
  with_items: "{{ mylist[2] }}"
```

Comment: With regex yes its working, to use that value as condition I need to register that msg .

Comment: However it only works when value are 6 or more digits. That value could be more or less , that is idea why we were trying to fetch child value stdout.

Comment: Better! I added six just to follow your example. Modifying in the answer ;)